# Aggregative entity with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 tables:

1. User - contains person's login and password.
2. Person - contains name and surname.
3. Role - specifies roles.

User binded with Person one-to-one.
User binded with role many-to-many.

I want create aggregative entity, contains all info e.g.:

```
public class AggregatedUser {

    private User user;
    private Person person;
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Have following questions.

1. Is it true way dealing with Hibernate?
2. How can I implement it?

Comment: An entity represents a row in a database table. So your class is not an entity. You said that Person has a one-to-one with User, which has a many-to_many with Role, so Person is already an "aggregative entity". From a person, you can have the information about the user it's linked to, and also about the roles of the user it's linked to. That's what associations are all about.

Comment: @JBNizet in my case I want Person class to hasn't User as field. Also I want User class to hasn't list of roles inside. So Person isn't "aggregative entity". What is best termin for AggregatedUser instead of 'aggregative entity"? "Aggregation of entities"?

Comment: Well, make it one, by adding the necessary associations.

Comment: @JBNizet I've founded examples for assotiations only between tables. AggregatedUses is not table. How can I assotiate it with other tables?

Comment: As I said: forget about this AggregatedUser class. Add the OneToOne assciation in Person, and the ManyToMany association in User. Then get a Person from the database, and you'll have access to its user and its roles.

Comment: @JBNizet so there is no way to deal with AggregatedUser? In my opinion it would be clearer: I'd have just user and aggregated user both.